# How to handle multiple windows in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While automating via Selenium WebDriver, I have the below scenario.  On a window, I copy the link and want to open the link on the new window(not in the new tab) and want to set focus on the new window. (Here the second window is not the child window of the first window)please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
WebDriver driverOne=new ChromeDriver();  
// navigate to your desired URL
driverOne.get("http://www.yourwebsite.com/");

// Do your stuff and copy the new link
// string newURL;

WebDriver driverSecond=new ChromeDriver(); 
driverSecond.get(newURL);
```

driverSecond will have a focus on the new window and once your actions are complete close the driverSecond.

Comment: If it's working for you mark this as the answer and upvote

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working, WebDriver driver2=new ChromeDriver();
  driver2.get(reff); "reff" is my link which is copied from the first window .

Comment: Not giving any error, but the focus is on the first window.

Comment: Also, I m trying to read an element from the second window which is not able to found

Comment: Please provide more details. what type of element, how are you identifying, are using XPath ?.

Comment: @FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='InputInnerSpan ReferalCode']")
 WebElement reffCode;        // Reff link which is copied       
  Thread.sleep(7000);
  wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  String reff=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(reffCode)).getText();
  System.out.println("=======Ref Link========"+reff);     WebDriver driver2=new ChromeDriver();
driver2.get(reff); and then after open the reff link in new window , here open the link in new window but not set focus on the new window

Comment: reff is the registration link and I want to register new user using that link, but I not able to access elements from the reff link

Answer (score 0):

In [Selenium 4](https://blog.testproject.io/2020/06/30/selenium-4-new-window-tab-screenshots/) (currently in beta), you the following will open a new window then automatically switch to the window:

```
  @Test
  public void openNewWindowForTestProjectBlog () {
    WebDriver newWindow = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
    newWindow.get("https://blog.testproject.io/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  }
```

Comment: I m using this solution, but not able to open new window

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;                                                        
 WebDriver new1=driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
     new1.get(reff);
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

Answer (score 0):

```
//assume - multiple windows are opened by clicking link or a button.    
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    
    for (String window : windows) 
    { 
       if (driver.getTitle().contains("***Something that is on new window***")) 
          { 
             driver.switchTo().window(window);
             //To get title of new window
             System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(window).getTitle());
          }
    }
```

Comment: hello my scenario is different, there is not any button or link on the main window where I am clicking on that, here the second window is not a child window, it is a separate window and I want to set focus on the second window